# Приложение и грамматическая основа

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите найти грамматическую основу во второй части предложения "Поднимаешься по склону на вершину кратера — дух захватывает от космического пейзажа". Одна основа "поднимаешься" (определенно-личное предложение), а вторая — "дух захватывает" или "захватывает"? Или это фразеологизм и оба слова являются сказуемым?
В предложении "Горы Шиханы — природный памятник Башкирии" подлежащее "Шиханы", а "горы" это приложение, следовательно, определение или подлежащее "горы Шиханы"? В подобных случаях нужно делить словосочетания или это один член предложения? Объясните, пожалуйста. "Кот Васька съел всю рыбу" — подлежащее "кот" или "кот Васька"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***Поднимаешься** по склону на вершину кратера — дух захватывает от космического пейзажа.*

Это БСП, сравнить: когда поднимаешься, то дух захватывает (СПП). Оба простых предложения односоставные.

***Поднимаешься** по склону на вершину кратера* — это обобщенно-личное предложение.  Действие может быть отнесено к любому лицу; автор как бы смотрит на себя со стороны, а читатель становится эмоциональным участником действия. Главный член выражен глаголом в форме 2-ого лица ед. числа, так как форма 2-го лица наиболее абстрактна  и удобна для обобщения.

***Дух захватывает** от космического пейзажа.*

Здесь используется устойчивое (метафорическое) сочетание "дух захватывает" в роли сказуемого (сказуемое + дополнение). Но по структуре это безличное предложение, личный глагол "захватывать" применяется в значении безличного.

О фразеологизме "дух захватывает" [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/дух+захватывает](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

2. ***Горы** Шиханы — природный памятник Башкирии. **Кот** Васька съел всю рыбу.*

В вузовской практике **все собственные имена** считаются приложениями.

В Сети дается такое же определение. К приложениям относятся имена, фамилии, клички, а также географические названия, названия газет, журналов, предприятий, художественных произведений, выступающие в роли определения, например: девочка Оля, мальчик Петя, собака Шарик, соседка Петренко, газета «Коммерсант», озеро Байкал. https://infourok.ru/konspekt-uroka-po-russkomu-yaziku-na-temu-prilozhenie-klass-3358022.html

Также это **свободное** (членимое) словосочетание. Список нечленимых словосочетаний дается у Кустовой (стр. 8) [Кустова. Синтаксис современного русского языка](https://infourok.ru/konspekt-uroka-po-russkomu-yaziku-na-temu-prilozhenie-klass-3358022.html)

Вывод. Подлежащим в приведенных предложениях являются родовые названия: *горы, кот*. *Шиханы и Васька* — это приложения.

Comment: Вы пишете, что к приложениям относятся имена, фамилии..., тоже самое читаем и в учебнике Т.А. Ладыженской 8 класс, а как же тогда в Справочнике по русскому языку Т.В. Шкляровой - "При сочетании имени собственного и нарицательного приложением является имя нарицательное. Собственное имя может быть приложением только в роли уточнения." В интернете читаем: Космонавт Гагарин проложил путь в космос- Гагарин подлежащее, космонавт приложение. Как же тогда объяснить детям? Кто прав?

Comment: В учебнике Ладыженской пример: девочка Оля (Оля-приложение), в учебнике С.Бархударова пример: врач Смирнова (Смирнова -подлежащее, врач -приложение). Так кто прав? Как учителю объяснять на уроке? Чья точка зрения правильная. А ведь детям сдавать ОГЭ и ЕГЭ, такие задания могут встретиться на экзамене

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ (как правильно?!)**

1. Да, школьная практика может **не соответствовать** вузовским учебникам. Но чья же точка зрения правильная? Попробуем разобраться.

Например: ***Гора** Казбек **расположена** на границе России и Грузии.* Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим *гора*. Здесь имя собственное является приложением.

Можно эту тему у посмотреть у Розенталя §185. Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим, имеющим при себе приложение http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

Но согласование часто делается по ближайшему слову: *Врач **Смирнова принимала** с утра.* Здесь женский род определяется по фамилии или же заранее известен говорящему. Вот и получается, что подлежащим является имя собственное.

***Собака** Трезор громко **лаяла**.* Здесь все наоборот, ведь имена животных нам род не подсказывают, да и родовое слово относится к обоим полам.

2. Поэтому в этой теме трудно найти **правильную** точку зрения.  **В практике** можно ориентироваться **на согласование** подлежащего (а не приложения) со сказуемым – вероятно, так и делают в школе.

Но согласование в общем случае – это **вещь ненадежная**, мы видим, что согласование по мн.числу может быть СМЫСЛОВЫМ ИЛИ ФОРМАЛЬНЫМ. К примеру, в действии участвуют несколько предметов, а сказуемое ставится в ед. числе (формальное согласование) в зависимости от разных факторов.

3. Возможно, в вузах дают определение **по семантике** (все имена собственные – это приложения, а основное содержание предмета передает родовое слово). Но на практике в теме приложений ориентируются на **формальном согласование**, которое имеет варианты. Так что трудности здесь не надуманные кем-то, а вполне **объективные**.
4. Соответственно, на экзамене нужна **определенная, пусть и условная** точка зрения. К сожалению, я не знаю, каковы современные школьные требования **на текущий момент.** Такую консультацию можно получить у практикующих школьных педагогов или в административных структурах, связанных с образованием.

И хорошо бы, чтобы школьники и педагоги **тоже понимали эту условность**, а не ждали от составителей учебников единственно верного ответа.